# Edit string from parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parsing

I am new to swift and could use some help with what I assume is an easy fix. I am pulling a string from the parse database but cannot figure out how to eliminate the option and brackets around the string itself. For example rather than "option(parse)" I just need "parse." Here is my code:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Kits")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("eXKU5kwMzj") {
    (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
        println(gameScore)
        let iKitPrice = gameScore?.objectForKey("Price")

        //The UI should only be updated from main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           self.yourLabel.text = "\(iKitPrice)"
        }

    } else {
        println(error)
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with JSON data is that it is it's have its "own" string. You can try convert it alone, but you will end up using huge nested if statements which ends up looking messy. Luckily, someone created a code that sifts through JSON data and gives you back usable types (for you it would be Strings) by use of a massive switch table.

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Look it up, it should help. Once you have it implemented you can call it by typing..

```
let json = JSON(Data : JSONData)
```

then to sift through, you use substrings.. (depending on the data, you match it with a string or int). You will need to cast it once you singled out the data

```
let myVariable = json["data"].stringValue
```

Answer (score 0):

if your string format is always like "option(string)", you can simply use replace function. I've never used Swift but after reading a couple of posts, thought this might help you.

```
let aString: String = "option(parse)"
let newString = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("option(", withString: "")
let output = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
println(output)
```

not sure this is exactly what you were expecting, but might help!